Nodemon is not working properly inside the docker container
While using anonymous volume and bind mount, I'm unable to use nodemon correctly inside the docker container. When I checked the file changes inside the container, I can see those changes seems like nodemon is unable to pickup those changes.
server.ts:-
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Testing this GET API..');  
  res.status(201).send('Hello from Docker and Kubernetes');
});

package.json:-
{
  "name": "rest-api-endpoints-for-todo-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon src/server.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "mssql": "^6.2.1",
    "node": "^22.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/mssql": "^9.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.2",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  }
}

Dockerfile:-
FROM node:22

WORKDIR /app/

COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm","start"]

Tried to check the logs of the container, but getting the below error:-
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall open
npm error path /app/package.json
npm error errno -2
npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent

Does anything in this workflow especially require Docker?  You might find it much easier to not insert an isolation system into your core development flow, and just run npm start using Node installed on the host system.

How are you running the container?  The container can't normally see files on the host at all.  There are common setups for this, but they generally involve overwriting absolutely everything in the image with volume mounts; at which point you may as well use the node image rather than a custom image; at which point it's the same as running Node on the host, but "in Docker".

As part of the learning I am using this project to run inside the docker container. And, also I'm running the container using this commands:-
"docker build . -t kushal2296/todo-list-backend:1.0"
"docker run -d --name get-api-check -p 8000:4000 -v "C:/NodeJS Projects/todo-list-backend:/app" -v /app/node_modules kushal2296/todo-list-backend:1.0"

Some discussion on the Docker forum suggests that the fix is rolling back to Docker Desktop 4.29
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-desktop-4-30-0-file-sharing-update-doesnt-work-possible-bug/141350/9

Nodemon is now working fine in my local WSL2 environment, but it's not working still due to the above mentioned error. Any suggestions are welcome.
